# Orbit in Blender by holding SHIFT + Middle buttom

Tags: navigation

Is it possible to change/customize the orbit command so that, orbit rotation can be done by holding shift and the middle buttom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is quite simple to change.

Navigate to *Preferences* > *Keymap* and select *Pan* for "Middle Mouse Action"

[image: Pan for Middle Mouse Action]

Comment: Tkank you!!! :)